# Is it possible to call API on EC2 from AWS IoT Rules Engine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, iot, aws-iot

I have use case like once data received in AWS IoT Rules Engine from things, I want to call API instead of dynamoDb, kinesis and lambda. I read FAQ https://aws.amazon.com/iot/faqs/ and doc but now found anything related to routing data to API on EC2 instance. This developer guide http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-create-rule.html shows how to route data to dynamoDb, S2, Kinesis, SNS and machine learning. Is it possible to route data to EC2 instance from IoT Rules Engine?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a iot rule to connect to lambda and in lambda function you can call your EC2 API.

Comment: but this flow will additionally add charges of lambda service. Is there any other alternate option?

Comment: `iot rule > lambda > ec2` is the simplest and preferred way, if you dont want real time processing of your data you can create rule to call S3 to store your event and then from ec2 you can fetch these events process it and then delete it from s3.

Comment: You could also publish to an SNS topic to which you have subscribed your ec2 api.